# Нужны ли запятые?

Tags: запятая

Вдали, у линии горизонта, виднеется церковь. Нужны ли запятые?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Правильно: Вдали, у линии горизонта, виднеется церковь.

ПОЯСНЕНИЕ

В данном случае мы имеем уточняющее обстоятельство, так как эти обстоятельства  нельзя считать неоднородными, обозначающими разные признаки.

ДАЛЬ - это  далеко простирающееся пространство, она представляется наблюдателю как максимально удаленное. Если видна линия горизонта, то "вдали" - это и есть "у линии горизонта". Таким образом, уточняющее обстоятельство говорит о том, что горизонт просматривается.

Answer (score 1):

"у линии горизонта" - это уточняющее обстоятельство места, которое выделяется запятыми

Answer (score 0):

Вот если это уточняющее обстоятельство места, тогда нужны. А если нет, то нет.